# How to choose Lucene DocValues type?

Tags: solr, lucene

i have a long field type to index timestamp  and i use lucene build my app's index , i found lucene5.1.0 class enum DocValuesType have six type  :

[image]

**which type is better choice to long filed sort ?**

Thanks for you answer.

Answer (score 0):

`NUMERIC` is fine!
For `Long` type field, there is no need to store value in DISTINCT-OFFSET model, although `SORTED_NUMERIC` will save disk usage.